# FTP installation

Tags: ftp

Is there a possibility to install GUI ftp on ubuntu(EX: filezilla server on windows)
I have tried gadminproftpd but it is not working properly.
Suggest some other tool.

Comment: Built in file manager Nautilus can connect to FTP and transfer files. I do not know which version of Ubuntu you have. Run Files or nautilus and you should see "Connect to Server" at the end of the list of places at the left side. Connect to the server by typing ftp://<username>:<password>@<servername>/. Put you data instead of words enclosed with <>.

Comment: He is talking about server, not client.

Comment: Is there a possibility to install GUI ftp server on ubuntu(EX: filezilla server on windows) I have tried gadminproftpd but it is not working properly. Suggest some other tool.

Comment: You have server with GUI or you wish to install some web based solution?

Comment: Why would you need a gui on the server for ftp?  You install it on a desktop and connect to the server. Otherwise I would suggest to use a webbased ftp.

Comment: I have a server with GUI and i need a ftp server (tool based) where i can create users and mange them from a tool based.

Comment: I have tried installing Gadmin proftpd,but it is not working properly is there any other tool where we can manage users.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to install `proftpd` and `webmin`.
You will get web based access for ftp server configuration

Instalation of `proftpd`

```
 sudo apt-get install proftpd
```

Installation of `webmin`

First you need add Webmin official repository and make sure that all packages are up to date.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add the following lines:

```
 deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
 deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

Fetch and install the GPG key:

```
sudo wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
sudo apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
```

Install Webmin with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webmin -y
```

You can access the webmin panel using web browser. Webmin use 10000 as its default port. https://ip-address:10000 then login as super user or root access priviliges. If you are using a firewall, please open port 80 and 10000 to enable access to the control panel.

Then once logged in using the menu system browse to Webmin configuration the select Webmin modules.

[image]

ProFTPD is a standard module in Webmin so we need to select standard module in Webmin then browse to select the module

[image]

You will then be presented with all the standard modules. Browse to ProFTPD and install it.

[image]

At the end you will get web based tool for `proftpd` configuration.

[image]

More you have [here](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ProFTPD_Server)